# Check user profile in view in PlayFramework?

Tags: security, templates, playframework

In my Play application, I've added Secure module. But I haven't found a way to check user profile in views. For example, one of the possible roles is "admin". When viewing certain pages, a button should be visible to admin's only. How to do that?

My first idea was to check session variable but I found nothing there. Security object is not available in views. Then I thought about putting data in there by overriding **onAuthenticated** method in my authentification controller, but I'm not sure that is the best way to proceed.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your own security module that extends controller.secure.Security, then within your view you can do this:

```
#{if controllers.MySecurity.check("isAdmin") }
   ...template code...
#{/if}
```

Comment: That is indeed what I was looking for. My error was the package omission. It threw a NullPointer... I must be really tired to make that kind of mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the deadbolt module for role checking?
http://www.playframework.org/modules/deadbolt-1.0/home